# Pass data - object from child to parent Angular 6

Tags: parameter-passing, angular6, eventemitter

In child component, I have a datatable, when I click on the row, I will get data and keep it in `branchToDivision`, I also have a button, when I hit that button, I can send `branchToDivision` to the parent component.

*Child component*

```
@Output() messageEvent: EventEmitter<BranchDto> = new EventEmitter<BranchDto>();
branchToDivision: BranchDto;
onSelect(record: BranchDto) {
        this.branchToDivision = new BranchDto();
        this.branchToDivision = record;
        console.log(this.branchToDivision);
        console.log(this.branchToDivision.brancH_CODE);
    }
acceptBranch() {
        this.onSelect(this.branchToDivision);
        this.messageEvent.emit(this.branchToDivision);
        this.branchModalDivision.hide();        
    }
```

*Parent Component*

```
branch: BranchDto;
getBranch(branch: BranchDto): void{
        this.branch = branch;
        console.log(this.branch);
        console.log(this.branch.brancH_CODE);       
    }
```

*Parent HTML*

```
<branchModal #branchModal (messageEvent)="getBranch($event)" ></branchModal>
```

I try to log branch property but it is undefined, What's wrong? Any idea is helping me well.

Comment: Update, I can send the object to parent but cannot read its property. I don't know why It is undefiend

Answer (score 6):

This is a way to send information from child component to parent component:

**parent.component.html:**

```
<div>
    <child (getData)="getData($event)"></child>
</div>
```

**in parent.component.ts:**

```
public getData(value): void {
    console.log(value) // welcome to stackoverflow!
}
```

**in child.component.ts:**

```
import {Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Output() public getUserData = new EventEmitter<string>();

this.getUserData.emit('welcome to stackoverflow!');
```

I hope my help is effective ツ

Comment: I can log the object but can not log its property, your solution also did not work for me.

Comment: dont use "getUserData". there is no event for it. use  like   this.getData.emit('welcome to stackoverflow!');

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.